# Convert unicode string to byte string

Tags: python, unicode

I get a string from a function that is represented like `u'\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0'`, but to process it I need it to be bytestring (like `'\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0'`).

How do I convert it without changes?

My best guess so far is to take `s.encode('unicode_escape')`, which will return `'\\xd0\\xbc\\xd0\\xb0\\xd1\\x80\\xd0\\xba\\xd0\\xb0'` and process every 5 characters so that '\xd0' becomes one character represented as '\xd0'.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

ISO 8859-1 (aka Latin-1) maps the first 256 Unicode codepoints to their byte values.

```
>>> u'\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0'.encode('latin-1')
'\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0'
```

Comment: That's smart. My first option would be `bytes(map(ord, x))` but it may be much slower...

Comment: confirmed this produces the desired result

Comment: @JBernardo That only works in python 3; it's not clear from the text, but the odds are the OP is on python 2.

Comment: @Zack maybe you could use `str(bytearray(...))` instead of `bytes`. Or even worse: `''.join(map(chr, ...))`

Comment: throws 'ordinal not in range'