# Convert unicode string to string

Tags: python

I have these variables:

```
s1 = '\xd1\x98\xd1\x83\xd0\xbd'
s2 = u'\xd1\x98\xd1\x83\xd0\xbd'
```

How can I transform variable `s2` to be same as `s1` so that comparing both will return `True`.

Comment: Ooops, found the answer right here that solves the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174790/convert-unicode-string-to-byte-string But why should I encode to Latin-1 when text is in Cyrillic? Or better, why doesn't `s2.encode('windows-1251')` work?

Comment: That looks to me to be UTF-8, `u'\u0458\u0443\u043d'`, `јун`.

Comment: This is already posted in Stackoverflow.

Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174790/convert-unicode-string-to-byte-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert `s1` to be the same as `s2`:

```
s1 = '\xd1\x98\xd1\x83\xd0\xbd'
s2 = u'\xd1\x98\xd1\x83\xd0\xbd'

s1 = s1.decode('unicode-escape')
```