# Convert unicode string into byte string

Tags: python, unicode

I have a string like:

```
s_str: str = r"\x00\x01\x00\xc0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04"
```

I need to be able to get the corresponding byte literal of that unicode (for `pickle.loads`):

```
s_bytes: bytes = b'\x00\x01\x00\xc0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04'
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65874499/16153744) the solution of using `s_new: bytes = bytes(s_str, encoding="raw_unicode_escape")` was posted, but it does not work for me. I got an incorrect result: `b'\\x00\\x01\\x00\\xc0\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x04'` that has two backslashes (actually representing only one) for each one that it should have.

[Also here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49990817/16153744) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11174804/16153744) a similar solution is proposed, but it does not work for me either, I end up getting the double backslashes again. Why does this occur? How do I get the `bytes` result I want?

Comment: Other than the solution in the answers [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49990817/16153744) also works.

Comment: What "byte literal of that unicode" mean? Unicode has just code points, no byte representation (so abstract). It also defines few encodings, but so you should specify which encoding. Note: your initial string is already problematic: what do you mean with `\x`? Whant do you mean with `\xc0`? '\x' should not be used on unicode strings (but just on encoded strings or binary data). For unicode just use codepoints (\u and \U). I think your main problem is that you are mixing too many concepts (on a non recommended way), so it is easy to get it wrong.

Comment: It is not possible to get `s_not_bytes` (the result of `s_new`) from `s_str` as you have shown.  `print(repr(s_str))` and post that.

Comment: The `"raw-unicode-escape"` encoding is what you want for the problem you described, and works for the input you show. Based on the answer that was given, and the symptoms described, the diagnosis is that `s_str` *actually contains* the backslashes. I [edit]ed the question to reflect that. I assume that's what you were trying to get at by talking about "raw Unicode"; but none of that part actually described it properly.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have byte escape codes as shown below (length 9) or you wouldn't get the `s_not_bytes` result:

```
s_str: str = "\x00\x01\x00\xc0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04"
```

You have *literal* escape codes (length 36), and note the `r` for **raw string** that prevents interpreting the escape codes as bytes:

```
s_str: str = r"\x00\x01\x00\xc0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04"
```

Note the difference.  `\\` is an escape code indicating a literal, single backslash:

```
>>> '\x00\x01\x00\xc0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04'
'\x00\x01\x00À\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04'
>>> r'\x00\x01\x00\xc0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04'
'\\x00\\x01\\x00\\xc0\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x04'
>>> len('\x00\x01\x00\xc0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04')
9
>>> len(r'\x00\x01\x00\xc0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04')
36
```

The following gets the desired byte string by converting each code point to a byte using the `latin1` codec, which maps 1:1 between the first 256 code points (U+0000 to U+00FF) and the byte values 0x00 to 0xFF.  Then it decodes the literal escape codes, resulting in a Unicode string again so once more encode using `latin1` to convert 1:1 back to bytes:

```
s_bytes: bytes = s_str.encode('latin1').decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin1')
print(s_bytes)
```

Output:

```
b'\x00\x01\x00\xc0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04'
```

If you *did* have `s_str` as posted, a simple `.encode('latin1')` would convert it:

```
>>> s_str: str = "\x00\x01\x00\xc0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04"
>>> s_str.encode('latin1')
b'\x00\x01\x00\xc0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04'
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves the issue. I was reading this from a file using ```open(file,'r')``` and I guess that creates a raw string.

Comment: And is there a way of reading from a file containing (raw text) either ```b'\x00\x01\x00\xc0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04'```or ```\x00\x01\x00\xc0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04``` so that it will be considered directly a string of bytes of length 9?

Comment: @TeresodelRíoAlmajano Reading a file doesn’t create  a raw string. Raw strings are a way of creating string literals in code without interpreting escape codes. Your file had text with escape-code-like text. You can `open(file,encoding='unicode_escape')`  if needed, but it would be better to post an actual sample of the file in case their is a better solution.

Comment: "and I guess that creates a raw string" It does not "create a raw string". There is not such a thing as a "raw string". However, reading a file into a string does mean that the string contains what the file actually contains - if there's a backslash followed by a lowercase n, then it's a backslash followed by a lowercase n, **not** a newline. Escape sequences **only** apply to *string literals in your source code, unless you explicitly do something to interpret them*. They apply *before the code runs*.

Answer (score 0):

I was about to post the question when I encounter a valid solution almost by chance. The combination that works for me is:

`s_new: bytes = bytes(s_str.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode-escape'), encoding="oem")`

As I said I have no idea why this works so feel free to explain it if you know why.

Answer (score 0):

You might simply use `.encode("utf-8")` to get desired result i.e.:

```
s_1 = "\x00\x01\x00\xc0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04"
s_2 = s_1.encode("utf-8")
print(s_2)
```

output

```
b'\x00\x01\x00\xc3\x80\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04'
```

Comment: No, that does not solve the problem of the double backslash. At least for me.

Comment: @TeresodelRíoAlmajano what version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using Python 3.9. 
But the other answer explains why I was not getting the desired result.